# Autofilter based on combo box value?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to place a combo box above an "Issue Status" column to filter the whole sheet based on the value selected from this column.  Ideally, the combo box would have three options--"Open", "Closed", and "Any".

How can I go about doing this?

I tried the following code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim sFilter As String
    sFilter = ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Application.Caller).List(ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Application.Caller).Value)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, sFilter
End Sub
```

However, this is throwing an error:  `Run-time error 1004:  Unable to get the DropDowns property of the worksheet class.`

Also, it is listing values several times in the combo box.  For example, index 1 of the combo box = "Open", index 2 also = "Open", etc.  I want to only display distinct values and filter based on that.

Is there a better approach to this?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a filter, Data>Filter.

[image]

Comment: As you can tell, I'm not very good with Excel.  Is there a way to make the filter a drop-down box with only those options?  The filter itself is more powerful and customizable, but I like the simplicity that a combo box offers.  EDIT:  Actually, nevermind.  The person who originally set this spreadsheet up asked for a dropdown, but I see that the other filters are set up this way.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1496816, you will always use the distinct data in your column. ;) Good luck with your sheet!